# How to get client IP address from inside a Azure Kubernetes with a LoadBalancer service

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-load-balancer

I'm getting the node IP address instead of the client IP. Is it possible to get the client IP with a service of type `LoadBalancer`? Or will I need to use a ingress controller?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-svc
  labels:
    name: app-svc
    environment: dev
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
  ports:
    - name: http-port
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
      name: app-deploy
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You do not need any Ingress controller. However it is required to set the value of the `spec.externalTrafficPolicy` Service field to "Local" (the default is "Cluster") in Microsoft Azure.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ...
```

See [Using source IP](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/source-ip/#source-ip-for-services-with-type-loadbalancer).

Comment: for fast experiment I use `kubectl edit svs/pentagon-balancer` and just change `Cluster` to `Local`. Now I can see real user IP in `X-Forwarded-For` header on backend